# Extract and Add raster class attributes to vector file attributes in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, feature-extraction, raster-attribute-table

I have a shapefile having (say 20 polygons). There are 20 rows in the attribute table of this shapefile (1 corresponding to each polygon). I have a binary raster with two classes 1 and 2. I want to calculate and extract the area corresponding to class 2 of raster in each of these polygons.

How can this area be added to attributes of shapefile and show the area in 20 rows of 20 polygons? How to do this with minimal manual effort in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Spatial Analyst extension, you can do the following:

- Select [Tabulate Area](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) tool to calculate the area of both classes (1
  and 2) within the 20 polygons shapefile
- The tool will ask to choose zonal layer and a zone field, you can choose either the name or the id field for the polygons, but id field is better
- Select the raster that represents classes (2 classes in your case) and the field which is usually Value (pixel values)

[image]

- The output table will produce the area of both classes (1 and 2). You can remove class 1 if you do not need it
- Finally, in ArcMap right-click the zone layer, point to `Joins and Relates`, and click `Join` to join the output table to the original shapefile based on the id field that you have selected when you identified the zones.

Comment: Thank you for resolving my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it worked :)